# Unexpectedly assign in pandas by df.loc and single-element list

Tags: python, pandas

When I assign new value to DataFrame by df.loc method and a list containing single element, pandas behaves not the way I expected.

For example (in python 3.6 and pandas 0.22.0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3]],columns=["A", "B", "C"])

# a list has two or more elements
df.loc[0, ["A", "B"]] = ["X", "Y"]
df
   A  B  C
0  X  Y  3

# a list has single element
df.loc[0, ["C"]] = ["Z"]
```

as I expected

```
df
   A  B  C
0  X  Y  Z
```

but the result is

```
df
   A  B    C
0  X  Y  [Z]
```

Is this behavior according to pandas' implementation?

I want to assign values the same way independently of how much elements a list has.

Comment: This looks like a bug...

Comment: Why would it unpack the double list, but not unpack the single element list?

Comment: I'm still not sure I'd expect assignment to a single column to unpack values of strings. If you specify multiple columns with an equal number of values, then the best bet is that you want to unpack. If I _wanted_ a list in that column, how else could I do it with this syntax? Just don't give a single-item list. I can see it both ways.

Comment: It would be great if you can submit it in github pandas

Answer (score 0):

It seems that assigning values by a list is not recommended.

c.f https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16864

Instead I will use element-wise method as follows:

```
for i, v in enumerate(["X", "Y", "Z"]):
    df.loc[0, ["A", "B", "C"]][i] = v
```

Thanks for all comments!

EDIT:

The above code does NOT work. It can't replace values in df. (But it works if 
*df.loc[0, ["A", "B", "C"]]* is replaced by pd.Series.)

the revised code is

```
for c, v in zip(["A", "B", "C"], ["X", "Y", "Z"]):
    df.loc[0, c] = v
```